# How to set tab title sticky on top with bootstrap-vue

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-vue

I am currently using bootstrap-vue to build a page with several tabs. This is the code in a nutshell

```
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div>
      <b-tabs content-class="mt-3 ml-3">
        <b-tab title="Settings">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Hello</h2>
          </div>
        <b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Question">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>World</h2>
          </div>
        <b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

How do I made the tabs title sticky in place, so whenever I scroll inside the tab, the tabs will always be on top? Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sticky-top` class, by adding `nav-wrapper-class="sticky-top"` to `<b-tabs>`.
This will make the navigation `sticky`, and will scroll with the page.

Depending on your setup, you might need to add a background color to the navigation, to avoid seeing the tab content under the navigation, as it's transparent by default.
That's why I use `bg-light` in the example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>



<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs content-class="mt-3 ml-3" nav-wrapper-class="sticky-top bg-light" card>
      <b-tab title="Settings">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2 v-for="i in 15">Hello</h2>
        </div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Question">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>World</h2>
        </div>
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>

  <br v-for="i in 25" />
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could instead add a scrollbar (when needed) to the tabs content.
Meaning the navigation stays in sight.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.custom-class {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>



<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs content-class="pt-3 pl-3 custom-class" card>
      <b-tab title="Settings">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2 v-for="i in 15">Hello</h2>
        </div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Question">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>World</h2>
        </div>
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</div>
```